# How get attachment id from its title in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This does not work:

```
$args = array( 
    "post_per_page" => 1,
    "post_type" => "attachment", 
    "post_title" => trim( "My Attachment" )
);

//This is empty
$get_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I know that attachment exists with that post title because searching by id returns an object with `post_title = "My Attachment"`.

How can I find an attachment by its post title?

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117069/how-to-find-attachment-by-its-name

Comment: From my experience, you cannot use post_title in WP_Query. I've tried many times, and displaying "$query->request" (which is the generated SQL) never shows the title column being queried.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the delay ... 
You can use a direct query to the class WPDB..

```
global $wpdb;
$str= "My Attachment";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '$str' ", OBJECT ); 
if ( $posts ){
    foreach ( $posts as $post ){
        echo $post->post_title;
    }
}
```

But beware! protects your code from SQL Injection Attacks 
read more in http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks